# Using Omnipay in Laravel project

Tags: laravel, omnipay

I have to implement Omnipay library for online paymant system in PHP. I've read Omnipay documentation, but I don't get  how it works exactly.

```php
// Setup payment gateway
$gateway = Omnipay::create('Stripe');
$gateway->setApiKey('abc123');
```

What should pass on to create() method, and what is the purpose of setApiKey.

Where I should call these methods?

Answer (score 4):

Omnipay is a gateway agnostic library so when creating your gateway object using `Omnipay::create()` you need to specify the payment gateway you would like to use, in your example's case the gateway is [Stripe](https://stripe.com/gb) ([omnipay-stripe](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-stripe)) so you pass the gateway name into the `create('Stripe')` method.

You can find a list of the supported gateways on the php league website ([official](http://omnipay.thephpleague.com/gateways/official/)/[third party](http://omnipay.thephpleague.com/gateways/third-party/)).

Each payment gateway has different credential requirements, Stripe require an API key that you can find in your Stripe account settings and pass in to Omnipay via the gateway object's `setApiKey()` method as per your example.

As another example [Paypal](https://www.paypal.com/uk/home) ([omnipay-paypal](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-paypal)) require a username, password, signature and paypal account ID which you need to set on the gateway object:

```php
$gateway = Omnipay::create('PayPal_Express');
$gateway->setUsername(USERNAME);
$gateway->setPassword(PASSWORD);
$gateway->setSignature(SIGNATURE);
$gateway->setSellerPaypalAccountId(SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID);
```

An easy way to find out what methods are available for a particular gateway is to look at it's Gateway.php file; [Omnipay\Stripe\Gateway](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-stripe/blob/master/src/Gateway.php), [Omnipay\PayPal\ProGateway](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-paypal/blob/master/src/ProGateway.php)